# How to postpone loading a file until it's function is called?

Tags: autoload

Say I have `foobar_utility.el` that defines an interactive function `foobar_utility`.

How can I postpone loading `foobar_utility.el` until `foobar_utility` is called?

Example usage:

```el
(load (concat user-emacs-directory "foobar_utility.el") :nomessage t)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'foobar_utility)
```

Is there a better way  to do this besides moving the load into the key binding? e.g:

```el
(global-set-key
 (kbd "<f1>")
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (load (concat user-emacs-directory "foobar_utility.el") :nomessage t)
   (call-interactively 'foobar_utility)))
```

Comment: Would using `;;;###autoload` on the line immediately *before* the function `foobar_utility` suffice -- then, eliminate the call to `load` and let Emacs *autoload* the library automatically whenever the function is called the first time (either noninteractively or interactively)?

Comment: Maybe? I would then need to generate auto-loads I suppose? Probably all of this is easy when you know how - I just never set this up before.

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.  Here is a little snippet from abo-abo, which I assume works (but I have not tried it out):  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8044/2287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `(autoload 'foobar_utility "foobar_utility" nil t)` in your init file, and put `foobar_utility.el` in a directory in your `load-path`. Don't load the file explicitly.

See the Elisp manual, node [Autoload](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html).

---

In response to a comment:

This is an explicit sexp that invokes function `autoload`.  You can use it *instead* of using `;;;###autoload` cookies and generating an autoloads file from them (which you then load from your init file). All an `;;;###autoload` cookie does is let you generate a file with autoload sexps like the one I showed.

Cookies can be convenient when you write a library that has many function definitions. Individual calls to function `autoload` can be convenient when you just want to autoload, from your init file, some functions that are defined in other files.

Comment: Does this require `;;;###autoload` above the functions & generating auto-load files?

Comment: No. It's instead of using `;;;###autoload` and generating and autoloads file. All that cookie does is let you generate a file with sexps like the one I showed.